# If the intersection of ideals $I_{1},\ldots,I_{n}$ is contained in a prime ideal $P$, then one of them is contained in $P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $I_{1},\ldots, I_{n}$ and $P$ ideals in $A$ with $P$ prime so that $\cap_{i=1} ^{n} I_{i} \subset P $. Show that there's an $i_0 \in \{1,...,n \}$ so that $I_{i_0} \subset P$.

My first idea was to try to do induction on $n$. The case $n=1$ is trivial of course, but then I couldn't go farther since removing one of the ideals to consider the intersection of $n-1$ ideals means I can't guarantee that the intersection is inside $P$.

I'm trying to prove the straightforward way now but can't really accomplish much. I tried assuming that every ideal has an element that's not in the rest and trying to work from there but again, seems to not get me anywhere. I'm just not sure how to approach the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hint:** If $I_k\not\subset P$ for all $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, then there is at least one $r_k\in I_k\setminus P$ for all $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. What can you say about the product $r_1\cdots r_n$?

Comment: This answer only moves the induction on number of ideals to induction on number of elements.

Comment: @user26857: Indeed, I don't disagree with that. Still, it may be a formulation that's easier to work with for some.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seeing it this way made it a lot easier to approach.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $I_i \not\subseteq P$ for all $i$. Then there exist $x_i \in I_i$; $ x_i \notin  P$ $(1 \leq i \leq n)$, and
therefore $\prod x_i \in \prod I_i\subset \bigcap I_i$; but $\prod x_i\notin P$ ($P$ is prime). Hence $\bigcap I_i$ is not a subset of $P$.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of an ideal P being prime is, given any ideals A and B such that AB $\subset P$, either A $\subset P$ or B $\subset P$. Thus, if $\bigcap_1^{n+1} I_i \subset P$, then $(\bigcap_1^n I_i)I_{n+1} \subset \bigcap_1^{n+1} I_i \subset P$ so that either $\bigcap_1^n I_i \subset P$ or $I_{n+1} \subset P$. If the former, use induction hypothesis. If the latter, done.

**NOTE:** For commutative rings, the definition for prime ideals given above is equivalent to the usual one: for any two elements $a,b \in R$, $ab \in P \Rightarrow a \in P$ or $b \in P$ iff, for any two ideals $A$ and $B$, $AB \subset P \Rightarrow A \subset P$ or $B \subset P$.

Comment: That is not the definition usually given for primality of ideals in the context of commutative algebra, where one usually defines them as the completely prime ideals.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Maybe you want to say "non-commutative algebra".

Comment: @user26857, nope. I wrote exactly what I meant.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Well, then I have to admit that I have no idea what you want to say. What is a "completely prime ideal" in commutative algebra?

Comment: In non-commutative algebra one defines *prime ideals* and *completely prime ideals*, and the two concepts are different. In a commutative algebra the two properties are equivalent, though, and the usual way to define prime ideals in commutative algebra is to use the general definition of completely prime ideals. The definition of prime ideals to which Taylor is referring here, on the other hand, is that of *prime ideals* in the non-commutative context. Not making that clear can confuse most readers, specially newbies, who probably do not know that (...)

Comment: (...) the definition Taylor is using is equivalent to the usual one, and in fact Taylor's answer shows that the heart of the matter in the question is in fact in the equvalence of the two variants of primality.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I prefer the definition I gave for commutative rings, but I guess confusion is possible. I'll add a note.